# Diverging to Positive and Negative Infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Say I have some sequence $\{a_n\}$ with one subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\} \longrightarrow \infty$ and another $\{a_{n_j}\} \longrightarrow  -\infty$. In other words, the lim sup $a_n = \infty$ and lim inf $a_n = -\infty.$

Because the sequence clearly does not converge, I am guessing I can call $\{a_n\}$ divergent. However, does $\{a_n\}$ diverge to $\infty$ and $-\infty$, or does it diverge to neither?

Just trying to make some sense of the definition of "divergence to infinity." My guess is that $\{a_n\}$ diverges, but does not diverge to either positive or negative infinity, since we can always find some element of the sequence greater than an arbitrary $M$ and another element less than $M$.

Many thanks.

Comment: Consider the sequence $ (-1)^n n$, it satisfies the conditions you mentioned at the beginning
Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes! That sequence seems to fit my description. Any ideas regarding the divergence issue?

Comment: The last part is true as well and the sequence I just gave satisfies the last part

Comment: It diverges, full stop. *Diverges to* $\infty$ is just verbal shorhand for a particular kind of divergence behavior that a sequence of the kind that you’re talking about does not exhibit, and the same for *diverges to* $-\infty$.

Comment: So to say "diverges to infinity" does the following equality need to hold: lim inf = lim sup = $\infty$?

Comment: I agree with Brian M.Scott

Comment: @dirk5959: Yes, because you have to have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say a sequence [diverges](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergentSeries.html) if it doesn't converge.

It is an abuse of terminology to say that the sequence "diverges to $+\infty$" or "diverges to $-\infty$", though people use it frequently.

What typically is meant by diverging to $+ \infty$ is the following:

$$\text{For any $M>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$, we have $x_n > M$.}$$

Similarly, for diverging to $-\infty$.

Comment: Then it is not imprecise. And it is actually good to use that terminology since it gives more information about the sequence. A sequence that diverges to $+\infty$ is convergent in a compactification, property not satisfied by arbitrary divergent sequences. The concern raised in the comments above is that from the information given one cannot even tell if that sequence diverges to infinity.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle How is "a_k diverges to infinity" better than ""lim inf a_k = +infinity"?

Comment: @SphericalTriangle To say something is good is to imply that it's better than the alternatives, or at the very least not significantly worse. Your tone is rather rude.