# Suppose that every sequence in A has a convergent sub-sequence. Prove that A is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

My attempt:

*We will prove by contradiction, assume to the contrary that A is unbounded. Then we will show that if every sequence in A has a convergent subsequence then A is unbounded. But if A is unbounded, then we have a sequence $f_n$ that diverges to $\infty$ (1), diverges to $-\infty$ (2), or diverges to $\infty$ and $-\infty$ (3). But $f_n$ diverges to infinity then every subsequence of $f_n$ also diverges to infinity. Therefore, there is a sequence that has no convergent subsequence which is a contradiction. This holds for (2) and (3). Thus A must be bounded.*

Is this correct?

Comment: Assume that $A$ is unbounded... we will show...  $A$ is unbounded? The idea seems to be there. But I would work on some of the wording.

Comment: You should include some missing context: it seems that $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof needs to be cleaned up a little. You say you are using proof by contradiction, but then say

> ... assume to the contrary that A is unbounded. Then we will show that if every sequence in A has a convergent subsequence then A is unbounded.

That's not what contradiction means. What you mean to say is

> ... assume to the contrary that $A$ is unbounded. Then we will find a sequence in $A$ with a non-convergent subsequence.

This clearly states the aim of the argument, and presents a clear contradiction to the hypotheses.

The remainder of the proof is, I believe, a bit confused and longer than necessary. For instance, you asset the existence of a sequence $f_n$ in $A$ which diverges in one of three ways. How do you know such a sequence exists? Once you know that it exists, why deal with three separate cases? What does divergence to $\infty$ and divergence to both $\infty$ and $-\infty$ mean? If a sequence diverges to $\infty$, how do you know every subsequence diverges to $\infty$? Some of these questions have good answers, but regardless, they should be addressed in a rigorous proof. I think a simpler argument is

> By the definition of unbounded, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $a_n\in A$ so that $|a_n|>n$.

Now consider the sequence $(a_n)$. It is a subsequence of itself. If you can show that the (sub)sequence $(a_n)$ does not converge, then you are done.

Answer (score -2):

Your second sentence doesn't make sense, and should be removed. "Diverges to infinity" is imprecise; see this question: [Diverging to Positive and Negative Infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232559/diverging-to-positive-and-negative-infinity) . You should probably be more explicit in your reasoning that "But [if] fn diverges to infinity then every subsequence of fn also diverges to infinity."

Comment: Diverges to infinity is not imprecise and it is not the moral to take away from the comments in the linked question. The answer to the linked question is also not a good source to follow.

Comment: This should really be a comment.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle Saying "Diverges to infinity is not imprecise" is simply bare assertion. "diverges to infinity" is unclear as to whether it's unbounded, limsup = infinitiy, or liminf = infinity. "it is not the moral to take away from the comments in the linked question" is not a coherent statement. If you have a problem with the linked question, you should explain what it is.

Comment: @copper.hat This is an answer to the question. It is not a comment.

Comment: @Acccumulation: It does not answer the question. It suggests a clarification.

Comment: @copper.hat The question asks whether the proof is clear. Saying that proof could use clarification answers the question of whether the proof is clear.

Comment: @Acccumulation The very answer in the link explains itself why it is not imprecise (contradicting its own second sentence). Plus, I had already explained there why the comments in that question make sense, while the answer there, and this one don't.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle How does the answer show it is not imprecise? Simply because we can *assume* that someone meant something else, doesn't mean it isn't imprecise. The phrase "lim inf a_k = +infinity" clearly and unambiguously conveys that for all M, there is an N such that n > N -> a_n > M. "a_k diverges to infinity" could just mean "unbounded". "Plus, I had already explained there why the comments in that question make sense" No, you haven't.